# How to fix javascript not working on newer jquery library but working on older version jquery library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have this javascript code whhich makes checkbox work as radio

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function() {$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
        $('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', false);
        $(this).attr('checked', true);
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<label title="cat"><input name="" type="checkbox" checked>cat</label>
<label title="dog"><input name="" type="checkbox" >dog</label>
<label title="lion"><input name="" type="checkbox" >lion</label>
<label title="fish"><input name="" type="checkbox" >fish</label>
<label title="turtle"><input name="" type="checkbox" >turtle</label>
```

Which was working when i was using older jquery library of version 1.8.3
but when i tried to include the newer jquery library of version 1.11.0 , its not working,

how can i fix it ?

here is http://jsfiddle.net/6upmbbf0/

if you change the jquery version on top left to 1.8.3 or lower it works but above 1.8.3 it doesnt.

Answer (score 3):

The correct method to retrieve and update a checkbox's checked state is [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/). The [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) simply retrieves or updates the attribute value; ***it does not necessarily update the underlying state of the input***.

---

[jQuery Core 1.9 upgrade guide](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#attr-versus-prop-) mentions that behavior is changed, which explains why your code worked in jQuery < version 1.9.

Comment: using the `not()` selector with `prop()` is even a better solution as you're not toggling the checkbox twice in the first place. As provided in my answer. Added your suggestion to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use `not()` instead of toggling the checkbox 2 times. If you exclude the checked checkbox in the first place, and uncheck the others, it works better.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').not($(this)).prop('checked', false);
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6upmbbf0/3/

edit, added suggestion by Salman A to use `prop()` instead of `attr()`

Comment: with this example, user can uncheck the item by double clicking it, so its not same as radio button., thanks using prop now.

Answer (score 1):

Use 'prop' Instead of 'attr' as

replace code

```
$(function() {$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
        $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
    });
});
```